MySQL root password reset
I've spent many an hour trying to reset my mysql root password with no luck.
I'm running an up to date patched Ubuntu server 22.04.4 with mysql 8.0.36.
My latest attempt is using
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &

followed by
mysql -u root

or
sudo mysql -u root

but I'm met with the response
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)

This is true as it doesn't look to be running on port 3306.
Using
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking PORT=3306 &
also doesn't work.
MySQL rungs quite happily on TCP 3306 when started using
sudo systemctl start mysql.service




chris@ubuntu-util:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
[1] 7261
chris@ubuntu-util:~$ 2024-06-05T06:49:43.386242Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2024-06-05T06:49:43.390991Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
mysql -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to sort this?

Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683179/10249977

MySQL rungs quite happily on TCP 3306 when started I do not see the facts which allows to say that MySQL is running... do you see mysqld in the processes list? does it is listening on localhost:3306? Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists. Does it is absent really? if not then create it otherwise check the permissions in the filesystem. --skip-networking forbids IP connection, only sosket connection can be used. But your client tries to connect via localhost - check client settings in the [client] section of my.ini.

/var/run/mysqld only existed when mysql was running normally. I've created this and changed ownership to mysql as per ownership when mysql creates it; it didn't help.
Using sudo to run commands allowed mysql to run but it still exited out with:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
This is true.
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
then
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
shows TCP 3306 and 33060 aren't listening. They are when systemctl starts mysql.
Not sure where 33060 comes from. I'm only running for Zabbix server and phpipam.

I sorted this with 'apt purge mysql-server-8.0', reinstall and then configuring a root password using mysql_secure_installation.
Instructions from https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-22-04/#secure-mysql-installation
My databases were still present. Having the security of a vm snapshot is a good thing.
